# SSRS change column heading based on parameter value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

[image]

I am using text based optional parameter in SSRS. If there is no value in parameter then I would like to show column heading as "Invoiced" and when some one search based on that parameter then I like to show column heading as "Payment Summary"

[image]

Comment: you have to use Condition based heading here..

Comment: I am trying =IIF(Parrameter.PaymentNumber.value="","Invoiced","PaymentSUmmary")

Comment: are you using this piece of code in header part?

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/reporting-services/sql-server-reporting-services-basics-customizing-ssrs-reports/ use this

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the reference on the parameter wrong. If you add a parameter to your report with:

```
'Label1
=Heading1

'Value1
="H1"

'Label2
=Heading2

'Value2
="H2"
```

You can put the following expression in your heading:

```
=IIF(Parameters!YourReportParameterName.Value = "H1", "Heading1", "Heading2")
```

If you want to check the parameter for no value use:

```
=IIF(Parameters!YourReportParameterName.Value = Nothing, ...
```

Comment: Hi I am doing same =IIF(Parameters!YourReportParameterName.Value = Nothing,"Heading1","Heading2") . But this way I am getting error in the column heading.So basically I like if end use enter no value in Payment Number parrameter then in column heading it should show "Invoice number". If they enter some value to particular search some value then column heading shoud by Payment Number. Thanks

Comment: Did you replace the name with the real parameter name (`YourReportParameterName`) ? If it is not working try the expression with a value that exist in the parameter and check if it is working.